# Get location in scene for pixel?

Tags: python, rendering, image

Given a pixel on the rendered image, is there any easy way to get the 3D location that the pixel corresponds to in the scene using python? i would really like to know before I go through trying to do the math to get it myself.

In case it makes a difference, I'm using an orthographic camera.

Comment: It is possible in the game engine, using the 'kx_camera.getScreenVect()' call. Not sure about the viewport.

Comment: It's possible in the viewport too, but rendered image? Not sure... What is the application?

Answer (score 2):

There are utility functions to convert 2d region coordinates to 3d:

[bpy_extras.view3d_utils](http://www.blender.org/documentation/blender_python_api_2_70_release/bpy_extras.view3d_utils.html)

There's also a method to cast a ray in the scene:

[Scene.ray_cast](http://www.blender.org/documentation/blender_python_api_2_70_release/bpy.types.Scene.html?highlight=ray_cast#bpy.types.Scene.ray_cast)

... but it might not work with orthographic view.