# How to get world coordinates of pixels?

Tags: python, rendering, scripting, camera

Using a Blender python script I want to get the world coordinate of a specific pixel (or all).

Assume a camera has been defined (focal length, fov/angle, sensor size,etc.), and orientated/pointed as desired. Also, a large surface is defined, so the camera rays would actually "hit" objects in the scene (& not cast into infinity).

For example, Given 4 corners pixels of camera, where do they in fall in world coordinates (XYZ)?

Alternatively, a script could export the world coordinates (XYZ) for all pixels, then a "camera ray hit map" could be generated.  *There's probably a better name for this.*

From the very similiar question, ["Get location in scene for pixel?"](https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/7106/get-location-in-scene-for-pixel), there are recommendations to use:

[bpy_extras.view3d_utils](http://www.blender.org/documentation/blender_python_api_current/bpy_extras.view3d_utils.html) & [Scene.ray_cast](http://www.blender.org/documentation/blender_python_api_current/bpy.types.Scene.html?highlight=ray_cast#bpy.types.Scene.ray_cast)

However I'm new to blender, and ray-tracing in general, and it is not clear to me how to proceed with these functions.

Comment: Related: http://blender.stackexchange.com/q/7397/599