# How to get the worldspace location of a rendered pixel from Python

Tags: python, rendering, scripting

I need a way to find the underlying 3D coordinates for each pixel of the camera in Python.

I to create a function like:

GetCoordinatesForPixel(xPixel, yPixel)

which returns a (X, Y, Z) vector.

I found the following threads:

[How to get world coordinates of pixels?](https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/16433/how-to-get-world-coordinates-of-pixels)
which is supposed to be a duplicate of this one:
[How to render world position pass](https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/7397/how-to-render-world-position-pass)

The latter solution works in that it procudes a render. However, I do not see a way to access those values in Python.

Comment: Did you look at this post http://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/7106/get-location-in-scene-for-pixel? You will have to play around with it a little, but this might be headed in the right direction.

Comment: Why would you need to render multiple times?

Comment: Once for the actual image I want to estimate on and once to get the ground truth values.
@BlendingJake I tried to work with bpy_extras.view3d_utils but so far I am not really sure how to handle the arguments. But I may be able to figure it out:)

Comment: @user1033657 I wasn't able to find much info on it, but just keep playing and you'll probably get it.

Comment: re-opening, @user1033657 would like to edit the question (to make it not a duplicate)

Comment: Would this help? http://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/16472/how-can-i-get-the-cameras-projection-matrix

Answer (score 1):

Blender's Python API currently doesn't expose access to the pixel value of render passes.

(You can access image pixels but renders's are a more complex structure).

However since you mention you need to store the values in a file, just save the OpenEXR file, this will store the values in a file.

Comment: Exactly how would you read these coordinates in .exr image tho? I just loaded an .exr image created from world position pass in Blender https://gofile.io/d/sN7OWF using python OpenEXR,  and all the (r,g,b) values are integers, wouldn't they all be float if they represent global coordinates?